# Edit woocommerce Login register page

Tags: authentication, registration, edit, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce for an eCommerce website. I want to add one more field in Login Regiser page. On this page there are three fields in registration (Email, Password and Re-enter password) and I want to add one more field for phone number.

Can anybody help me ? Thanks in Advance
http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

Answer (score 10):

If anyone else is curious on how to add additional fields to the login/register/any other account forms. You can achieve this quite easily since WooCommerce has added those to their **templates** folder. All you have to do is copy-paste the form you need to modify from **plugins>woocommerce>templates>myaccount** and drop it into your own theme. After which, you can add your extra fields and add any other functionality to make them work using http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/

Hope this is of help to anyone who's been stuck on this.

Answer (score 3):

I Use the "Register Plus Redux" plugin and use the "billing_phone" Database key to map to the correct field in the the User database. You can also have the user add other Information such as "'billing_address_1" and any others.
Best Regards
Marc

Comment: It does not work well,  order of fields does not as usual, I mean reenter email field is not under the email field, same problem occurs for password field

Answer (score 3):

*Old post, but this answer deals with the question as asked and provides a direct answer form the WordPress Codex*

I have modified the code from the pages linked to act inline with the zipcode example that appears on the validation page. Each page within the codes used different examples, I just made them all the same.

## Add the custom field

#### Plugin API/Action Reference/register form

The 'register_form' action hook is used to customize the built-in WordPress registration form.

Use in conjunction with 'registration_errors' (for validation) and 'register_post' (save extra data) when customizing registration.

**WordPress MS Note: For Wordpress MS (Multi-Site), use the 'signup_header' action to redirect users away from the signup.** *(emphasis mine, took me a while to realise this)*

#### Example

This example demonstrates how to add a new field to the registration form. Keep in mind that this won't be saved automatically. You will still need to set up validation rules and manually handle saving of the additional form fields.

```
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_add_registration_fields' );

function myplugin_add_registration_fields() {

    //Get and set any values already sent
    $zipcode = ( isset( $_POST['zipcode'] ) ) ? $_POST['zipcode'] : '';
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="user_extra"><?php _e( 'Extra Field', 'myplugin_textdomain' ) ?><br />
            <input type="text" name="user_extra" id="user_extra" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( stripslashes( $zipcode ) ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
    </p>

    <?php
}
```

link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_form

## Validation

You need to validate the user input (obviously) and should run that through`registration_errors` filter hook. Be mindful, the `$errors` variable may already be populated by other errors from the registration process. As in the examples, you would add your error to errors already contained therein.

#### Returning an Error

```
function myplugin_check_fields( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    $errors->add( 'demo_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: This is a demo error.', 'my_textdomain' ) );
    return $errors;
}

add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_check_fields', 10, 3 );
```

#### Validating a Custom Field

*(this next section deals specifically with validation of the custom field)*

Assuming you wanted to validate a postal code field that you have already created using the register_form hook, you might validate the field like so:

```
function myplugin_check_fields( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( ! preg_match('/[0-9]{5}/', $_POST['zipcode'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'zipcode_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid Zip.', 'my_textdomain' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_check_fields', 10, 3 );
```

link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors

## finally, don't forget to save the custom field's data!

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

if ( isset( $_POST['zipcode'] ) )
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'zipcode', $_POST['zipcode']);
}
```

link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

## A complete example

At the end of all this I ended up coming across a tutorial to do exactly this. In this example they are adding a `First Name` field:

```
//1. Add a new form element...
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );
function myplugin_register_form() {

$first_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';
    
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name', 'mydomain' ) ?><br />
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(  $first_name  ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
    </p>
    <?php
}

//2. Add validation. In this case, we make sure first_name is required.
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
    
    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) == '' ) {
    $errors->add( 'first_name_error', sprintf('<strong>%s</strong>: %s',__( 'ERROR', 'mydomain' ),__( 'You must include a first name.', 'mydomain' ) ) );

    }

    return $errors;
}

//3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
    }
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form